How to have instructional text in Excel?
I would like to know how to place instructional text (like placeholder text) that disappears on click in some Excel cells (C9, C21, C58, C96).
I would need the instructional text to be gray and the real text to be black.
Is there a way to do this?

Possibly using the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

One way to achieve this would be to use an ActiveX textbox that is linked to a cell instead of a cell directly (See at the end for the approach using a cell only).

Here's a demo of how this can look like:

Here's the code I had in the Worsheet code module:

Const PLACEHOLDER_TEXT = "My placeholder text"

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    'Clear text content
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT Then
            .Text = ""
            .ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    'Add the placeholder text if user exits without filling the field
    With TextBox1
        If .Text = vbNullString Or .Text = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT Then
            .Text = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
            .ForeColor = vbGrayText
        End If
    End With
End Sub


And to add a linked cell, you can enter Design Mode, right-click the textbox > Properties > Edit the Linked Cell entry using the standard Excel address format:


For the approach with a cell and using Worksheet_SelectionChange as suggested by BigBen, you could use something like this inside the worksheet module:

Option Explicit

Const TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C2"
Const PLACEHOLDER_TEXT As String = "My placeholder text"

Const GREY_COLOR = 10921637
Const BLACK_COLOR = 0

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Replace(Target.AddressLocal, "$", "") = TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS Then
        'Clear text content
        With Target
            If .Value2 = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT Then
                .Value2 = ""
                .Font.Color = BLACK_COLOR
            End If
        End With
    Else
        'Restore placeholder text if needed
        Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = Me.Range(TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
        With Rng
            If .Value2 = vbNullString Then
                .Value2 = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
                .Font.Color = GREY_COLOR
            ElseIf .Value2 = PLACEHOLDER_TEXT Then
                If .Font.Color <> GREY_COLOR Then
                    .Font.Color = GREY_COLOR
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
        
End Sub



Is there a way without using activex textbox because there's not much option in term of layout formatting with this method ? And I would like it to be in a cell ?

@ClaraMonspiette - I've edited my answer to add another method using a simple cell as well.

How can we apply the code to several cells ?

@ClaraMonspiette - With a different placeholder text for each cell?

Yes, I would like to give different instructions for each cells.

@ClaraMonspiette - Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78703204/5958842

Unfortunately, your solution is only half working as the texts are still gray at the end.

It works for me. You can check by putting the code in Sheet1 of a new workbook.

For simplicity, I've changed the color constants to use non-negative numbers.
